# Python Apache Beam, How exactly do Fixed Windows Work?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am using a SubPub to publish data into BEAM. I have been trying to use Fixed windows with a 60 second interval however when I publish data the data is immediately printed on my screen. Shouldn't it only be printed every 60 seconds?

The code is like this:

```
objects = lines | 'Ex' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractorAndCounter())
windowed_lines = (
            objects
            | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
            | 'print' >> beam.Map(print))
```

whereas ExtractorAndCounter is a simple parser and nothing else.

Comment: Can you confirm that ExtractorAndCounter returns TimestampedValue with both element and timestamp?  Ex https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements

Answer (score 2):

In the beam model the windowing function for a PCollection, the fixed windows in your example, is used "the next time you apply a grouping transform". For example a GroupByKey or a Combine. Map is element wise, rather than a grouping transform.

There is some good information in section 7.1 at the following link.

[7.1 Windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing)

Answer (score 0):

So the problems seems to be that I did not have anything properly processing what came out of the windows. Once I added a GroupByKey below and then the "print" it started working properly.